# iOS5 UITapRecognizer for UIScrollView interfering with buttons. How to fix?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I have a bunch of `UIButton`s within a `UIView` within a `UIScrollView`. I'm trying to add a tap recognizer to the scroll view. The tap recognizer fires, but now none of my buttons work.

I know that in iOS5, `UIScrollView` can somehow pass a touch event down to the control hierarchy  after being done with it. Anyone can help me figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the `UIGestureRecognizer` property `cancelsTouchesInView` to NO.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                                             action:@selector(singleTap:)];
singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[tapableView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
[singleTapGestureRecognizer release];
```

From [UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> A Boolean value affecting whether touches are
>   delivered to a view when a gesture is recognized.
>
> When this property is YES (the default) and the
>   receiver recognizes its gesture, the touches of that gesture that are
>   pending are not delivered to the view and previously delivered touches
>   are cancelled through a touchesCancelled:withEvent: message sent to
>   the view. If a gesture recognizer doesn’t recognize its gesture or if
>   the value of this property is NO, the view receives all touches in the
>   multi-touch sequence.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that was wanted behavior, but if it is for your case and @AlexStone 's case then jolly good! :-)

Answer (score 2):

For me a combo of the above answers worked

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userDidTap:)];
tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
[tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizersToFail:self.scrollView.gestureRecognizers];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

-

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] || [touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This would make the gesture recognizer fail on the button - not sure how this correlates with the question.

Comment: Yes, it will. In my case that is wanted behavior. The question is not clear on this point to my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` method of the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, which is documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate), to accomplish the same thing. It offers a little more flexibility, for instance, if you want to cancel certain touches, but not others. Here's an example,

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: That actually is not the same thing. When returning NO, the gesture recognizer does not handle the touch. When returning YES, the UIView does not handle the touch. cancelsTouchesInView set to NO means both, the gesture recognizer AND the view receive the touch.

Comment: You are correct. If you wanted to accomplish both you could potentially handle the touch event here *before* returning NO.