# UITouch events with UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a custom UIView subclass and I added a UITapGestureRecognizer to it.

I notice that when I click once and immediately double click on the view touchesBegan:withEvent is only called twice. If I remove the GestureRecognizer it is called 3 times. I also notice that when I click once and double click after some significant time, touchesBegan:withEvent is called 3 times as expected. What would explain this? Can I let the GestureRecognizer not interfere with the UITouch events?

Answer (score 0):

Your UITouch events and your UIGestureRecognizer are likely competing with each other for the touch events. There are a few ways to make them work together. See some of these related posts:

- [UIButton inside a view that has a UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344341/uibutton-inside-a-view-that-has-a-uitapgesturerecognizer)
- [iOS5 UITapRecognizer for UIScrollView interfering with buttons. How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250485/ios5-uitaprecognizer-for-uiscrollview-interfering-with-buttons-how-to-fix)